# Question about stack permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, stacks

I encountered an exercise in which I am struggling to understand the solution provided even though I spent a lot of time trying to figure it out.

The exercise is the following and was taken from the book "The art of computer programming - Volume 1 by Donald Knuth"

[image: Reference: The art of computer programming Vol 1]

> Imagine four railroad cars positioned on the input side of the track in Fig. 1,
> numbered 1, 2, 3, and 4, from left to right.
> Suppose we perform the following sequence
> of operations (which is compatible with the direction of the arrows in the diagram and
> does not require cards to "jump over" other cars):
>
> (a) move car 1 into the stack;
>
> (b) move car 2 into the stack;
>
> (c) move car 2 into the output;
>
> (d) move car 3 into the stack;
>
> (e) move car 4 into the stack;
>
> (f) move car 4 into the output;
>
> (g) move car 3 into the output;
>
> (h) move car 1 into the output.
>
> As a result of these operations the original order of the cars, 1234, has been
> changed into 2431.
>
> Show that it is possible to obtain a permutation $p_1,p_2 ... p_n$ from $1,2 ... n$
> using a stack if and only if there are no indices $i < j < k$ such that $p_j <p_k <p_i$

The answer is :
If $j < k$ and $p_j < p_k$, we must have taken $p_j$ off the stack before $p_k$ was put on;
if $p_j > p_k$, we must have left $p_k$ on the stack until after $p_j$ was put on. Combining these
two rules, the condition $i < j < k$ and $p_j < p_k < p_i$ is impossible, since it means that
$p_j$ must go off before $p_k$ and after $p_i$, yet $p_i$ appears after $p_k$·

I tried to apply this reasoning to the permutation <3,1,2> which obviously can't be obtained using the constraints of the question,
we can see that the indices $1 < 2 < 3$ satisfies:
$p_i = p_1 = 3$
$p_j = p_2 = 1$
$p_k = p_3 = 2$
Therefore this permutation is not obtainable, I tried to follow what was said in the answer but I still don't get it, I will appreciate any hints\clarifications.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets try to understand this scenario

We have three elements $i,j,k$

Their order of arriving at the stack is $j,k,i$ ($p_j<p_k<p_i$)

Their order of getting out of the stack is $i,j,k$ ($i<j<k$)

The answer argues that this scenario is impossible to happen, lets try to see why

---

consider elements $j$ and $k$

We know that $j$ enters the stack before $k$, and that $j$ gets out of the stack before $k$

The only way for this to happen is, $j$ enters the stack, $j$ gets out of stack before $k$ enters, $k$ enters the stack  $(1)$

---

consider elements $k$ and $i$

We know that $k$ enters the stack before $i$, but $i$ gets out of the stack before $k$

The only way for this to happen is, $k$ enters the stack, $k$ waits till $i$ enters the stack, $i$ enters the stack, $i$ gets out of the stack $(2)$

---

consider elements $i$ and $j$

We know that $i$ gets out of stack before $j$ (this suffices to arrive at our contradiction) $(3)$

---

Now lets recap

Order of arrival $j,k,i$

Order of departure $i,j,k$

In order for this to happen we need

$(1)$ : $j$ enters the stack, gets out of stack before $k$ enters, $k$ enters stack

$(2)$ : After $k$ enters the stack it needs to wait till $i$ enters, $i$ enters the stack then gets out

We can see that for $(1)$ and $(2)$ to happen, we need $j$ to get out of stack before $i$ even enters the stack

But this contradicts $(3)$ : $i$ gets out of stack before $j$